# Why is my ReceivedBufferSize huge? Up to 65535 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, server

So I am playing around with the Tcp protocol in C# and figured I would connect to my server.
When I connect to my server it notifies me just fine. but then I go to check the ReceivedBufferSize and it's this `receivedBuffer={byte[65536]}`

When in reality it only gives back a few bytes.

Why is this happening?
Sending this back to my client doesn't do anything either so I removed that part.
I figured it's because the packet is so big.

This part right here

```
byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

returns `receivedBuffer={byte[65536]}`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static IPAddress remoteAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    public TcpListener remoteServer = new TcpListener(remoteAddress, 7777);
    public TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnListen_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StartServer())
        {
            client = remoteServer.AcceptTcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            while (client.Connected)
            {
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
                    {
                        receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
                        clientStream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            remoteServer.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Server Started...");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here, it's only 15 bytes
[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing 65536? According to the docs, the default is [8 KiB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: The `byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];` contains that much, and I have no idea why it's so big

Comment: If it is that big, why not create a smaller buffer?

Comment: The `ReceiveBufferSize` property is how many bytes you are expecting to receive in the buffer at a time, not the actual count of bytes received, if that's the confusion.

Comment: Oh, okay! Yeah that makes sense then, I was curious to why there was so many empty bytes

Comment: Oh, that was the confusion? Yeah: you can't resize arrays, so you have to set a fixed size and it will fill it as much as it can with what's received, and then you can use the return value of Read to know how many bytes you actually received.